# Convert List to A String

Tags: python, string, pyspark

I am having problems keeping the data into a string format. The data converts to a list once I perform a split on each row (x.split). What do I need to do to keep the data in a string format?

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    document = sc.textFile("/content/sample_data/dr_csv")
    print type(document)
    print document.count()

    document.take(5)
    document.takeSample(True, 5, 3)

    record = document.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
    record.take(3)
```

Comment: Can you show sample input and expected output data?

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a copy of x to split it without affecting x as follows:

```
temp = x
record = document.map(lambda temp: temp.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.join` method if you want to get a string with all of the elements of the list. Suppose you have `lst = ['cat', 'dog', 'pet']`. Performing `" ".join(lst)` would return a string with all the elements of `lst` separated by a space: `"cat dog pet"`.

```py
''.join([str(i) for i in document.map(lambda x: x.split(',')])
```